# Как поставить другой index page для мобильных устройств WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, плагин

Как сделать только так, что бы при загрузке сайта, у юзера с телефона, стартовая страница была другая?

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165211/how-to-set-a-different-static-homepage-for-mobile-version-wordpress Можете ещё посмотреть в сторону плагинов, уверен для Wordpress найдутся.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, логика довольно проста, например, можно использывть стандартное опредиление WordPress - `wp_is_mobile()`. Если нужен более большой список устройств, то добавить в функции темы, что используется фильтр, который будет разширять массив агентов.
Пример использывния:

`if(wp_is_mobile()){
/* Выполни все, что нужно для мобильных, например подгрузку другой страницы темплейта или редирект */
}`

Например, для мобильных подгружать другую часть темплейта, у вас есть две части-темплейта в корне темы, `for-pc.php` и `for-mobile.php`. В нужном месте кода:

`(wp_is_mobile()) ? get_template_part('for-mobile') : get_template_part('for-pc');`

Код будет использывать мобильный темплейт `for-mobile.php` если индефицировано, что пользыватель зашел с мобильного устройства, во всех других случаях подгружается темплейт для ПК `for-pc.php`.